# What to do if a found bug has already been reported?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, bug-report

Should I add it to bug tracker or not? How should I proceed? Should I ignore it?

Comment: What's the problem; if you know the bug has been already reported by someone from your team/colleagues then just ignore it otherwise if you are again reported the same one then someone will mark it as DUPLICATE with previous defect ID and it's closed. To avoid this you may just open the previously reported bug match the steps add new screenshots with current date & test environment and Take a note for your future reference.

Comment: You say "Oh, this has already been reported. Cool." and then carry on with your day.

Comment: Ohh.. Great Suggestion...! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happened with the previous report? **Was an item created** for the defect due to that report?

If so, check the defect for things such as:

- is it *really* the same defect? (Scenario, data, ...)
- is the existing defect clear and complete, can I improve it?
- was it reviewed by the Product Owner, and what's the **severity**?

For example, the PO might consider this defect having low severity, but **your renewed input might change that** (e.g. if you just found that more than one user is impacted).

So, in any case, it can't harm to add your findings (even just the fact that you still encountered it on date X, environment Y, data Z) if the defect item is already complete.

In all other cases, you'll be adding new information. **Conclusion**: definitely do not ignore a bug just because you know it has been "reported" once before.

Comment: The bug is already reported and has an id in a bug tracking system. It just has not been fixed yet.

Comment: Then you can ignore it unless you have relevant information not yet in the existing tracker item.

Comment: Yup.. If you know the previously added bug is exactly similar to this .. Then you may just ignore the things.. Keep tracking on this already reported bug instead of adding new one...If its High priority/Severity then Inform to your Dev/ Team, when it will be gets resolved? Just keep watching and tracking on it.. .

Answer (score 1):

All these scenarios we need to check before marking as a Duplicate Bug in any  Bug tracking tool. When you know that issue has already recorded by your team members, then check below options to confirm:

- First we need to check the status of the reported existing bug in the Bug tracking Tools, whether the bug  has "DEFERRED" status or not.
- If it is then  we need to wait until that issue  get fixed in the NEXT release by Dev Team.
- If it is in "OPEN" status then still Bug is not yet fixed by the DEV team, so no need to post another DUPLICATE Bug.

If it has "CLOSED" status, then need to "REOPEN" it, by providing valid screen shots and justice that Bug has NOT yet Fixed in the current Release.

> Conclusion: Before ignoring any Bug we need to verify and validate the exact scenario as per our Expectations.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please re-open the bug.
2. Add more description and steps in the bug.
3. Prepared bug video / screenshot of bug and attached.
4. Enter the exact steps to reproduce the issues in the bug report and discuss bug with developer.

Answer (score 0):

Record it, validate that it is truly the same, and mark it as a duplicate if applicable.

- This will help inform decisions for addressing it.

  - Multiple reports means more users affected which may justify a higher priority.
  - Specific users or organizations may have different Service Level Agreements (SLAs).
  - The attributes (role, organization, permissions, etc.) of the users affected may help find the true root of the issue.
- This supports tracking and updating all users reporting the issues on the status of any fixes.
- The duplicate link may, depending on the system, permit updating all related tickets through updates to the primary one.

Ignoring it or not filing the additional report can be very detrimental.

Comment: Creating a bug only to mark it as duplicate is, in my experience, useless, as duplicates are never ever looked at (again).

Comment: Thank you the comment.  It may have been useless in your experience; my answer presents how it can be useful.

Comment: Recording invalid reports can also provide data that can be useful in other areas such as improving communications.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the following things [top software testing companies](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company#!reasons-to-use-our-services) follow in this case:

- If the said bug is in 'OPEN' state then wait for the dev team to work
  on it and add any additional description, steps or screenshot/video.
- If the bug has been 'Deferred' by dev team for next release then we
  can do the following:

  1. If the bug is affecting multiple users, then it's severity 
       can be updated to higher one
  2. In the absence of above case, we should wait for it get fixed in 
       upcoming release.

These are some of the practices a [software qa company](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company#!get-a-free-quote) tackles such a situation.